# django, how to redirect to a specific page based on user role using auth_login

Tags: django, authentication

How can we redirect the user to a specific page based on user role using auth_login!

For example:

1. A user with role "CRM" should be redirected to dashboard
2. A user with role "Admin" should be redirected to Activities

Can this be done in Django using auth_login?

Answer (score 0):

If by "role" you're referring to a permission, you can use has_perm() to test for the presence of a specific permission.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm